# Foreign key value not populating automatically

Tags: c#, entity-framework, foreign-keys

I've created a foreign key reference to the 'ApplicationUser' entity in my 'YogaSpace' entity seen below, but when I create a new YogaSpace and save it to the DB the column 'ApplicationUserRefId' is null? Shouldn't it contain the user id from application user without me inserting it into the entity before I save it? I know the answer would seem to be yes because I have another member in 'YogaSpace' called Images and it gets the 'YogaSpace' entity id automatically without me inserting it into the 'Images' entity before I save. So I don't have to insert the id there. How come it doesn't insert the user id with 'YogaSpace'?

```
public class YogaSpace
{
    public int YogaSpaceId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<YogaSpaceImage> Images { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(128)]
    public string ApplicationUserRefId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ApplicationUserRefId")]
    public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public DateTime MembershipCreated { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Birthdate { get; set; }
    public Gender Gender { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<YogaSpace> YogaSpaces { get; set; }
}

public class YogaSpaceImage
{
    public int YogaSpaceImageId { get; set; }
    public byte[] Image { get; set; }
    public byte[] ImageThumbnail { get; set; }
    public string ContentType { get; set; }
    public int Ordering { get; set; }

    [Index]
    public int YogaSpaceRefId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("YogaSpaceRefId")]
    public virtual YogaSpace YogaSpace { get; set; }
}
```

Here is how I create a 'YogaSpace' entity. You can see I don't put anything into 'ApplicationUserRefId', **BUT** I expect it to autopopulate with user id from Application User, just like YogaSpacerefId gets auto populated when I create an image and save it.

```
var newSpace = new YogaSpace
{
    Overview = new YogaSpaceOverview
    {
        Title  = viewModel.Title,
        Completed = ListingComplete.Incomplete
    },
    Listing = new YogaSpaceListing
    {
        Accommodation = (YogaSpaceAccommodation)viewModel.YogaSpaceAccommodation,
        SpaceLocation = (YogaSpaceLocation)viewModel.YogaSpaceLocation,
        SpaceType = (YogaSpaceType)viewModel.YogaSpaceType
    },
    Details = new YogaSpaceDetails
    {
        Completed = ListingComplete.Complete
    },
    Address = new YogaSpaceAddress
    {
        Completed = ListingComplete.Incomplete
    },
    DateCreated = DateTime.Now
 };

 yogaSpaceRepository.InsertOrUpdate(newSpace);
 yogaSpaceRepository.Save();
```

Comment: Where do you set the value of `ApplicationUserRefId`? Or indeed any of these variables? For all we know you could be just not setting the value, leaving you with `null`.

Comment: Hi Ben, maybe I wasn't clear in my question. I don't set the value of 'ApplicationUserRefId', but I expect it to be auto populated because I'm not setting the 'YogaSpaceRefId' in YogaSpaceImage when I create one and it auto populates the value for me. So why doesn't it autopopulate 'ApplicationUserRefId' ? I'll update my code to show how I create a 'YogaSpace' entity

Comment: You might not set the ID but you surely set the navigation property of an Image to a YogaSpace. i.e. var ysi = new YogaSpaceImage(); ysi.YogaSpace = someYogaSpace; Do you similarly set a YogaSpaces ApplicationUser to an ApplicationUser instance?

Comment: Show the code that "autopopulates" `YogaSpaceRefId`. There must be something essentially different than how `ApplicationUserRefId` is set.

Comment: I have the similar error when i add  [ForeignKey("JobeezUserInfoId")]
        public virtual JobeezUserInfo JobeezUserInfo { get; set; }